# MEF parts on shared folder and "run as administrator"

Tags: c#, mef, administrator

I build an C# app that use MEF parts as plugin. These part are loaded when my main application start. My app as above line in App.config for allow load MEF parts from a network shared folder.

```
<runtime>
 <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
</runtime>
```

So I my app is running as "current user", the MEF parts are loaded both in local or from network share folder. But if I run my application as "Administrator" (run as administrator), MEF are not loaded. Of course, I got same result, when I run VS2010 as Administrator.

My application is build for .net 4, x86. I use ExportFactory (CompositionInitializer and ExportFactory to the desktop) : http://mef.codeplex.com/discussions/207539

Is there special behavior when running MEF app/parts as Administrator ?

**EDIT : 08/07/2014**
Finally it work. This is my new runtime section in app.config file :

```
<runtime>
  <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
  <NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy enabled="false"/>
</runtime>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the administrator account does not have permissions on the folders where your MEF parts reside? Can you check the current user account when debugging and check if that user has the required permissions.

Comment: Sorry for this late answer. I believe your right, and for now, I just try using VS2010 as current user or run as admin. I don't understand why in some case, run as administrator work worst than run as current user. I test today an other strange behavior with "run as admin" and ObjectListView grid. When "run as admin", drag and drop from my desktop is not allowed. If I run VS2010 as current user, DnD work well.

Comment: infos : In security tab, for my VS2010 link, my account as same right and permissions as admin account.

Comment: this may be something to ask the MEF guys more directly.